# Pause/Resume javascript Pomodoro clock

Tags: javascript, timer, clock

I've been working on a Javascript pomodoro clock. I am able to set the session time and break time and it counts down without any trouble. But for some reason I can not get pause and resume to work. When the timer starts I capture the Date.now() and when I pause it I capture the current Date.now(). I find the difference and subtract from the duration, hoping to resume at the paused time, but it still keeps subtracting additional seconds. My code (from  [codepen](http://codepen.io/dsemel/pen/mOeEJQ))  is below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total;
  var i;
  var x;
  var y;
  var display;
  var minutes;
  var seconds;
  var duration;
  var sessionInterval;
  var freeze;
  var timePast;
  var t;
  var start;
  var clock;

  function timer(end) {
    total = Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(new Date());
    minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    return {
      'total': total,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };
  }

  function beginTimer() {
    start = Date.now();
    clearInterval(sessionInterval);
    clock = document.getElementById('display2');
    start = Date.now();
    sessionInterval = setInterval(function() {
      t = timer(duration);
      clock.innerHTML = 'minutes:' + t.minutes + '<br>' + 'seconds:' + t.seconds + '<br>';

      if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(sessionInterval);

        if (i === 0) {
          session();

        } else if (i === 1) {
          breakTime();
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function session() {
    duration = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + (x * 60 * 1000));
    beginTimer();
    i = 1;
  }

  function breakTime() {
    duration = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + (y * 60 * 1000));
    beginTimer();
    i = 0;
  }

  $(".sendInput").click(function() {

    if (x == null) {
      x = 25;

    } else {
      x = parseInt(document.getElementById("workTime").value, 10);
    }

    if (y == null) {
      y = 5;

    } else {
      y = parseInt(document.getElementById("breakMin").value, 10);
    }
    session();
  });

  $(".sendPause").click(function() {
    freeze = Date.now();
    timePast = freeze - start;
    clearInterval(sessionInterval);
  });

  $(".sendResume").click(function() {
    if (i === 1) {
      duration = new Date(((Date.parse(new Date())) + (x * 60 * 1000)) - timePast);
    }

    if (i === 0) {
      duration = new Date(((Date.parse(new Date())) + (y * 60 * 1000)) + timePast);
    }

    beginTimer();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="break: 5 minutes" id="breakMin">
  
<input type ="text" placeholder="session: 25 minutes" id="workTime">
  
<input type="button" value="Start" class="sendInput">
  
 <input type="button" value="Pause" class="sendPause">
  
<input type="button" value="Resume" class="sendResume">
  
<div id="display2">
</div>
```

Comment: `Date.parse(new Date())` doesn't make sense, use `Date.now()`.

Comment: @RobG This may be the problem: `Date.now() - Date.now()` evaluates to zero as one would expect. But `Date.now() - Date.parse(new Date())` seems to evaluate to anywhere between 5 an 800 millseconds in Firefox under Windows. It's as if `new Date()` calls into the OS which returns "some time later", or Firefox is using `new Date()` to multitask.

Comment: That is the lag between `new Date()` creating a new Date object, then `Date.parse` converting it to a string, parsing it back into a date, then returning the time value.

Comment: A better formatted version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMLVje?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major logic problem is within the resume function which does not reset `start` to a new notional value that is `timePast` milliseconds before the present. Using the original `start` value after a pause of undetermined duration simply does not work.

`Date.parse(new Date())` also appeared to be causing problems. Without spending time on debugging it further, **all** occurrences of  `Date.parse(new Date())` were simply replaced with `Date.now()`.

So a slightly cleaned up version of the resume function that appears to work:

```
  $(".sendResume").click(function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (i === 1) {
      duration = new Date( now + x * 60 * 1000 - timePast);
    }

    if (i === 0) {
      duration = new Date( now + y * 60 * 1000 + timePast);
    }

    beginTimer();
    start = now - timePast;  // <-- reset notional start time
  });
```

but please test it further - you may wish to investigate why `timePast` is added in one calculation of `duration` and subtracted in the other!

Comment: Sorry, I've been playing around with it since I posted my question which is why timePast is added in the second calculation, just doing some testing. I will try debugging some more.